# What are the advantages of using LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

What are the advantages of using LINQ over other data querying mechanisms such as SQL?

Answer (score 1):

you are likely to be pummelled for such an open ended subjective question.  But since you're here....

Start by reading [this post](http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx) on the LinqPad site.  And if you're thinking of getting up to speed on Linq then LinqPad (a free download) is an absolute must.